# Why does this straightforward google maps link not work on a Nexus 7?

Tags: android, html, google-maps, maps

https://www.google.co.uk/maps?t=m&cid=18135759454057787726&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=&z=16&vpsrc=0&iwloc=A

I have a client complaining that the above link is opening his maps app but giving an error

"unsupported link. Google Maps can't open this link"

Happening on his Nexus 7 and Samsung S6. Any ideas??

Comment: Make sure that your client has the latest versions of both google maps and streetview. Check this related [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/q7jpc-6vZMk;context-place=topicsearchin/maps/category$3Aviews%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false). Based also from this [thread](http://places.blumenthals.com/thread854b.html), when the client gets this message, it's usually because he just verified his account and the system needs to take some time to add you to Maps. This message usually goes away within 24 hours and sometimes within minutes from the time he verified his account.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your client has the latest versions of both google maps and streetview. Check this related [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/q7jpc-6vZMk;context-place=topicsearchin/maps/category%243Aviews%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false). Based also from this [thread](http://places.blumenthals.com/thread854b.html), when the client gets this message, it's usually because he just verified his account and the system needs to take some time to add you to Maps. This message usually goes away within 24 hours and sometimes within minutes from the time he verified his account.